# Send gcm push to android from Appengine

Tags: gwt, google-cloud-messaging

I was able to register from the android device to appengine
Once i register with the appengine i get the registrationId on the android app.
Using the registrationId i was trying to send the message to the android app from appengine server.

```
Sender sender = new Sender(App-Key);
Message message = new Message.Builder().addData("data", "hello client").build();
Result result = sender.send(message, registrationId , 5);
```

I have embeded the above code in a http post method.

But i get the following error:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
com.google.android.gcm.server.InvalidRequestException: HTTP Status Code: 401
    at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:177)
    at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:121)
    at com.google.android.gcm.demo.server.SendAllMessagesServlet.doPost(SendAllMessagesServlet.java:86)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:102)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:249)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:477)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
```

Can anyone please help me resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should catch the push intent onReceiveMessage of your GCMIntent service and create a notification with the extras (getExtras()) bundle of the push intent.

Follow this guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by making following changes to the code

for single android device:

```
Sender sender = new Sender(App-Key);
Message message = new Message.Builder().build();
Result result = sender.send(message, registrationId , 5);
```

for multiple android devices:

```
Sender sender = new Sender(App-Key);
Message message = new Message.Builder().build();
MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, list of registrationIds , 5);
```

However the notification goes to the android device from appengine but i was still wondering like how do i send the message to the android device along with the notification.

Comment: hello ,here you mentioned MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, list of registrationIds , 5);
so ,list of registrationIds is List<String>????